# vscode don't recognize java as a language

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I installed the Java Extension Pack, but vscode does not recognize java as a language, nor as a file.
He does not recognize how language must be why he does not continue the code.

**Extensions:** Debuger for Java, Java Dependency Viewer, Java Extension Pack, Java Test Runner, Language Support for Java, Live Server, Maven for Java, One Dark Pro, open in browser, Python, VS IntelliCode.

[image]

**Edit:** Now, vscode recognize java as language, but the color from the function/class don't change. http://prnt.sc/pqpryt

Comment: You may need to restart vscode after you have installed the extensions. Also check that the extensions are activated

Comment: Already restarted, already reloaded in the window, already reinstalled the extensions. And they are enabled

Comment: I think you need to have standard java project format like `project/src/main/java`

Comment: What [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file) is displayed in the lower right corner of the status bar?

Comment: try to press `F1->Create a Java Project`.see if it works.

Comment: I update the Question, thanks @Matt Bierner,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the rest of the problems by reinstalling VSCode (using Revo uninstaller). If you need to do the same, i recommend using [Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) to save extensions and basic configs (I'm not involved with the extension)